# Showing Invalid Argument

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a form with a submit button, but the code i created, keeps returning an error.

I tried this code:
`

```
function SubmitCard() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var crdSht = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Cards");

  var data
  [[ crdSht.getRange("A2").getValue(),
  crdSht.getRange("B2").getValue(),
  crdSht.getRange("C2").getValue(),
  crdSht.getRange("D2").getValue(),
  crdSht.getRange("E2").getValue(),
  crdSht.getRange("F2").getValue() ]];

      crdSht.getRange(crdSht.getLastRow()+1,1,1,6).setValues(data);
}
```

`
I was expecting the code to insert my data values in the row under the last row with data.

Comment: First of all you didn't define`data` correctly. You need `var data =`. Calling `getRange` for each cell is the worst possible way to code performance-wise. Why don't you get all range at once? `crdSht.getRange("A2:F2").getValues()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Sheet.appendRow()`, like this:

```
function SubmitCard() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const crdSht = ss.getSheetByName('Cards');
  const data = crdSht.getRange('A2:F2').getValues().flat();
  crdSht.appendRow(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
function SubmitCard() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var crdSht = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  var data = [[crdSht.getRange("A2").getValue(), crdSht.getRange("B2").getValue(), crdSht.getRange("C2").getValue(), crdSht.getRange("D2").getValue(), crdSht.getRange("E2").getValue(), crdSht.getRange("F2").getValue()]];
  crdSht.getRange(crdSht.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, 6).setValues(data);
}
```